# How was Walt unharmed after throwing the mercury fulminate on the floor in Tucos office?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In season 1 of [Breaking Bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad), Jesse visits Tuco in order to make a drug deal. Tuco takes Jesse's meth, beats him pretty severely, and doesn't pay him.

Later, Walt visits Tuco to make a deal and get the money he owes. While there, he throws [mercury fulminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury%28II%29_fulminate) on the floor. It causes an explosion that blows out the  windows. **How come Walt wasn't harmed?**

Comment: Actually Tuco and his two henchmen don't get harmed either ([watch the scene on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3avhU0N5lJI#t=2m21s)). Unlike Walter they don't even have a nose bleed. So the explosion didn't (seriously) hurt _anyone_, not just Walter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically, *he was harmed...*

[image]

The visible effects are the blood dripping from his nose and his ears, but this is symptomatic of possibly more serious (although obviously not life threatening) internal injuries.

If you're asking why he wasn't as badly injured as the rest of Tuco's crew, it's because they had no idea what was about to happen and he was entirely aware (being the propagator of the attack)..

Walt wasn't disorientated, confused or alarmed, unlike everyone else in the room who just experienced the physical effects of a surprise explosion!

Not to mention he was all jacked up on adrenaline..this is the more or less the beginning of his Heisenberg persona.

I miss Walt ... I'm Breaking Sad.